# In struts1.2 how to populate dropdown according to database value

Tags: jsp, listbox, jsp-tags, struts-1

I have a textboxes and one dropdown on html whose value is getting saved to database on clicking save button but on searching for the value all textboxes and radio button are getting populated except the foloowing dropdown ..

```
      <td align= "right" nowrap> 
                            <html:select property="standard">

                                <html:option value="I">I</html:option>

                                <html:option value="II">II</html:option>

                                <html:option value="III">III</html:option> ...
```

and for populating the values i am using th following code..

```
        stuform.setStandard((String)tempmap.get("STANDARD"));
```

**Note:** I have checked    stuform.getStandard() value is there but it is not getting displayed on jsp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dropdown list should be represented by a list of LabelValueBean objects in your form class as follows.

```
List<LabelValueBean> listOfStandards = new ArrayList<LabelValueBean>();
//popoulate the list
myForm.setStandardList(listOfStandards);
```

And in your jsp you can access the list in your drop down list as follows:

```
<html:select property="standard" styleId="standard">
    <html:optionsCollection name="myForm" property="standardList" label="label" value="value"  />
</html:select>
```

Note: Make sure you have a "standard" property in your form. The "standard" property will be set with the value of the selected item from the dropdown list.

Comment: Thnks susie.. it is saving to the database but on retreiving the results from database the standard dropdown is not getting populated.

Comment: should i set the myForm in session scope?

Comment: myForm.setStandardList(listOfStandards);----make sure the listOfStandards is populated.

Comment: ya it is...dropdown is getting populated with initial data and on clicking the 'save' button it is saving to database also but on searching for record it always populate my dropdown with first item of list(which is 'I' in this case).