# How to persist form bean object value to retrieve it later in Struts 1

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

**Using Struts 1.3**

I have a login form with username, password and a drop-down with some values like English, Deutsh and so on. When a form is submitted, the last value need to be persisted from the drop-down.

Following the code sample.

## Form Bean :

```
public class LoginForm extends ActionForm {

private String locale;

 public void setLocale(String locale) {
                this.locale = locale;
 }

 public String getLocale() {
     return locale;
 }


}
```

**JSP Code :**

```
<html:select property="locale" onchange="refreshPage(this.value)">
    <%
    Locale availableLanguages[] = DAOFactory.getConfigurationDAO().getAvailableLanguages();
    for (int i=0; i<availableLanguages.length; i++) {
        String localeNameKey = "com.web.gui.localeName." + availableLanguages[i].toString();
    %>
    <html:option value="<%= availableLanguages[i].toString() %>"
                 key="<%= localeNameKey %>"/>
    <% 
    }
%>
</html:select>
```

Now this JSP code generates the following drop down:

[image: Drop Downs]

[image: Full Login page]

**struts-config.xml**

```
<action-mappings>
  <action path="/login" type="com.web.gui.LoginAction" name="loginForm" scope="request" input="/loginForm.jsp">
  <forward name="setLanguage" path="/loginForm.jsp"/>
</action>

</action-mappings>
```

**Question :**

Now the problem is, when i enter the invalid username, password and select the language say Deutsch. the last language selected should be persisted and shown in the drop down as selected. But the drop down is initialized and the value is set to English.

When a form is submitted, the fields are validated. if they are not valid, then the error message is displayed and all the values are initialized to null. Now in my case i want to store the selected value of drop down and want to shown that value after validation (for invalid user).

**Modified the code :**

**In Bean class**

```
public class LoginForm extends ActionForm{
    private Collection dropDownList = null;

    public void setDropDownList(Collection dropDownList){
                    this.dropDownList = dropDownList;
            }

    public Collection getDropDownList(){
            if(dropDownList == null){
                    dropDownList = new Vector(10);
                    Locale availableLanguages[] = DAOFactory.getConfigurationDAO().getAvailableLanguages();
                    Properties properties = loadProperties(Locale.ENGLISH);

                    for(int i=0 ; i<availableLanguages.length ; i++){
                            String localeNameKey = "com.web.gui.localeName." + availableLanguages[i].toString();
                            String value = availableLanguages[i].toString();
                            String key = properties.getProperty(localeNameKey);
                            dropDownList.add(new LabelValueBean(key,value));
                    }
            }
            return dropDownList;
    }
}
```

**In jsp :**

```
<html:select property="locale" onchange="refreshPage(this.value)">
    <html:optionsCollection property="dropDownList"/>
</html:select>
```

Comment: Show your `struts-config.xml`

Comment: Added struts-config.xml file. Please check.

Comment: @primitiveType I haved added struts-config.xml file code. Please check and update. Is there anybody who can help me out on this.

Comment: yeah, we all are here to do the same... u need to provide the information

Comment: u are trying to say if the form is submitted and there is error of name/pass rather language , then the language must be there as preselected ?

Comment: @AshishRatan I mean to say if the user enter username = admin, password= 1234 and language as Deutsch. And if the username and password are wrong then the user is redirected to login page again with all fields blank and language selection drop-down with Deutsch as selected value. Moreover adding the screen shot of the login page

Comment: it should be selected if you use the same input as before validation, but you can use javascript to modify the value after the page is loaded.

Comment: @Roman Can you please elaborate

Comment: @AshishRatan  yes you get it right

Comment: @user958324 Indeed, what else do you want to know?

Comment: simple create a setter getter for the dropdown as long array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay!!.

First dont use Scriptlet tags thats bad practice.

Since you are using `Struts1.x` struts supports Select tag with their Tag library.

Below is the example code fragments to use dorpdown.

```
                <html:select property="langType">
                    <html:optionsCollection property="dropDownList"   value="key"
                        label="value" />   
                </html:select>
```

Create a memeber element 'langType' type `List` or `Map` in your Form Class. 
Set th list or map into that `langType` using setters in form.

Even when you redirect to same page it will hold the value for you in the dropdown that you selected previously.
But You need to set the dropdown everytime whenever you wanted to show.

Check this question answer they have explained how to use list as dropdown in Stuts1.x [Use List as Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273849/in-struts1-2-how-to-populate-dropdown-according-to-database-value)

**Where to set the DropDownList**

Dont set the dropdownlist in JSP using scriptlet tag.

Step1

Before you come to your Login Page (Assuming it should hit a action class)
in that action class set your drop downlist.

Before you come to your login page (Assuming it wont hit action class) then keep another layer of Jsp or redirect action which will hit action class so in action class you set your dropdown list.

Comment: I did all the things you said above but unable to understand where should i set the dropdown list in struts action or in jsp. Also sending you the code what i did till now. Check the modified code heading

Comment: I want to store the last selected value from the dropdown and set this further after page gets refreshed.

Comment: @user958324 What do you mean you want to store ? Do you want to store that in Database? What I understand is you want to show what user selected in drop down when user entered invalid login am I correct ?

Comment: yes you are right. the last selected value should be persisted to the corresponding bean.

Comment: Can you please check the code i have modified in the question above. Check the heading Modified the code.

Comment: I am not able to understand what do you  mean by the statement : "Set the list or map into that langType using setters in form".

Comment: In modified code whatever you have added is correct process.. Are you still not able to acheive this ?

Comment: No it still repopulate the dropdown list to its initial value.

Comment: Got the soluton. In my code somewhere, mapping.findForward("login") is set to action class, which i think refresh all the data to its initail value. Check the struts-config.xml file i have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot and for not using scriptlets.